# Save items from controller into array on Yes / No basis

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, dom, single-page-application

Having some trouble with angularJS i've only been working with it for two weeks and my javascript knowledge aswell is rather no existent so please take this into account.

Im currently making a hearing test app which all functionality is working apart from a reporting system im building into it.

Im wanting on a yes / no basis record at what frequency and DB they heard the sound from these two buttons.

```
<button ng-click='' type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></button>
<button ng-click='' type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg  glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
```

Here is an example of one of my controllers for 125HZ at 0DB as an example.

```
// 125 FREQUENCY START
myApp.controller('125Zero', ['$scope','ngAudio', function($scope, ngAudio) {

    $scope.title = "Frequency: 125Hz";
    $scope.frequency = "0Db"; 
    $scope.sound = ngAudio.load("audio/125_0.mp3"); // returns NgAudioObject
    $scope.previous =""
    $scope.next ="125Ten"
}]);
```

Im wishing to record the $scope.title and $scope.frequency attribute into and array for later processing.

this is as far as ive got with the idea

```
function result() {
$scope.results = [];


  $scope.resultService = function(){
    $scope.results.push();  
  }
```

}

with no results, i want to save both title and frequency into the array, and allow the program to move onto the next controller and do the same if the frequency is heard.

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Apologies if my code isn't the cleanest or ideal but as i explained this is my second week working with AngularJS

Thanks.

Comment: The question is not very clear:
1. From where do you get the frequency, sound, title values? 
2. is it something like when user clicks on button1 then you need the values (Frequency: 125Hz, 0Db) into an array? If he clicks button2 then you need to push another value to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add event listeners to the buttons:

```
<button ng-click='buttonPressed('okay")' type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></button>
<button ng-click='buttonPressed("remove")' type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg  glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
```

In your controller, add those methods:

```
myApp.controller('125Zero', ['$scope','ngAudio', function($scope, ngAudio) {

    $scope.title = "Frequency: 125Hz";
    $scope.frequency = "0Db"; 
    $scope.sound = ngAudio.load("audio/125_0.mp3"); // returns NgAudioObject
    $scope.previous ="";
    $scope.next ="125Ten";

    $scope.buttonPressed= function(outcome) {
       $scope.result = [];
       var tempObj = {};
           tempObj.title = $scope.title;
           tempObj.frequency = $scope.frequency; 
            // check for outcome to find out if it's okay or remove. 
            //based on that set the frequency here.
           $scope.result.push(tempObj);
           // add this to service
    } 
    }]);
```

To get this value in next controller:

You need to store that `$scope.result` inside a service. So create a service and push the $scope.result into that.

In your second controller, inject that service as a dependency and access the value there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and super quick response. :D